# error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github, http-status-code-403

I'm getting `HTTPS: 403` error while pushing to the repo:

```bash
Enumerating objects: 1007, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (264/264), done.
Writing objects: 100% (376/376), 139.79 KiB | 3.58 MiB/s, done.
Total 376 (delta 278), reused 151 (delta 101), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Git version:

```bash
$ git --version
git version 2.40.0
```

First, I was a collaborator to the project and this worked well about a month ago, but 1-2 weeks ago it stopped working, nobody touched the repo! Then I transferred this repo from user A to myself, I thought that permissions are broken, but I still can push to repositories created by myself with same tokens. So, credentials are correct 100%.

Also, an opened PR is associated with this repo, but I can neither push to the PR's branch nor create a new one, even though I'm an owner. What can cause this behavior and how to make it work?

P.S.: I didn't try to use `ssh` instead, this is, actually, not possible for me now, so I use `https`.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status 403 is "Unauthorized" - you've provided valid credentials and authenticated successfully, but the account you're using is not permitted to perform the action you've requested.

Unfortunately, there isn't enough information here to provide a concise diagnosis, but a few broad possibilities come to mind:

1. You moved the repo to your own account on the host, but didn't update the remote on your own system. Check `git remote -v`; if the remote URL is incorrect, then you can fix it with `git remote set-url $REMOTE_NAME $NEW_URL`.
2. You're using the correct URL, but you don't have write permissions to that repo.
3. You're using the correct URL, and you have write permissions to that repo, but the branch you're attempting to push to is protected and you don't have permission to push directly to that branch.
4. A proxy server is misconfigured.

Comment: 1) I changed remote to the new location, it didn't help, also note that until user A creates another fork old remote is redirected to the new one automatically; 2) How can I check those permissions (whether they're granted to me or not)? 3) What kind of protection do you mean? I even allowed to push force for those branches, I didn't find anything else; 4) I still can push to repositories created by myself and any repo, but this one.

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing to the repo just check "**Help.md**" and if it is present just check if the java version change has been mentioned in it or not and if yes then trying deleting it and then push. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my origin detail from `http` to `https` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the following process worked

```
https://github.com/rohit/xyz
```

to

```
https://github.com/rohit/xyz.git
```